# Trying to make a fill in the blank quiz with python 2.7 but program is not performing the way I want it to

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
print 'Welcome to General Quiz, a quiz where you are asked to select from three difficulty levels, with each level containing 5 fill in the blank questions'
print ''
print 'Rules:'
print '- These questions will be general knowledge based'
print '- Your score, which will be shown in the end, will be based on how many correct answers you get compared to the number of guesses you take' 
print '- It will not matter if you type anything lower or upper case'
print '- Some answers will require multiple words, so make sure you include spaces'
print '- For numbered answers, sumbit answers in numbers, not words'
print'' # These past few lines simply print out the rules for the user when they play this game

levelselect = 'no'# This variable will only set a condition for the following while loop

while levelselect == 'no':

    print ''
    level = raw_input ('Please select a difficulty (easy, medium, or hard): ').lower()# Prompts the user to select a difficulty and makes all letters lower case so it won't matter what case the user types in their input
    if level == 'easy' or level == 'medium' or level == 'hard':

        break # If the user's input is one of these three words, the program will break out of this loop, regardless of the value of the variable 'levelselect'

guesses = 0 # Used to record the number of guesses from the user to be displayed at the end of the game
score = 0 # Used to record the number of correct guesses the user gets correct later on in the game

print''

easy_questions = ['The chemical symbol (O) means _____',
                 '_____  is the best hockey player of all time',
                 '_____ is the year Canada became an independant country',
                 'The song "Sorry" was sung by _____',
                 'Steve Jobs is one the founders of  _____ ']
medium_questions = ['_____ is Canadas very first capital',
                 'The national team of _____ won the 2014 world cup',
                 'In a computer, RAM stands for _____',
                 'Your kidneys and your _____ are the organs that filter blood in your body',
                 'In Breaking Bad, the wife of Walter is _____ White']
hard_questions = ['In NASAs apollo program, _____ of their missions successfully landed men on the moom',         
                 '_____ was the year the NFL was founded',
                 'The first film to gross over one $1 billion is _____',
                 '_____ is the business with the worlds largest revenue',
                 'Lego was invented in the country of _____'] # This array contains all the answers with the blanks that are to be filled in

easy_answers = ['oxygen', 'wayne gretzky', '1867', 'justin bieber',
               'apple']
medium_answers = ['kingston', 'germany', 'random access memory',
                'liver', 'skyler']
hard_answers = ['6', '1920', 'titanic', 'walmart', 'denmark'] # This array contains all the answers, with corresponding indexes to the previous array

if level == 'easy':
    questions = easy_questions
    answers = easy_answers

elif level == 'medium':
    questions = medium_questions
    answers = medium_answers

elif level == 'hard':
    questions = hard_questions
    answers = hard_answers

totalQuestions = 5 # The questions array contains 15 questions, with the first 5 being easy, the next 5 being medium etc. and this helps to identify the finishing point of the asking of questions
questionNum = 0

def check_answer(user_answer, system_question, system_answer):

    if user_answer == system_answer:
        return ''
        return ('Correct!')
        return system_question.replace ('_____', system_answer) # Shows question with the blank filled with the correct answer
        score += 1 # Increases user's score by 1
        guesses += 1 # Increases user's guesses by 1
        questionNum += 1 # Makes the code in this while loop move onto the next question in the questions array and the next answer in the answers array

    else:
        return ''
        return ('Incorrect, Try Again')
        guesses += 1

while questionNum < totalQuestions:
    Question = questions[questionNum]
    Answer = answers[questionNum]

    print ''
    answer = raw_input (Question + ': ').lower() # Prompts the user to answer the fill in the blank question

    print check_answer(answer, Question, Answer)

print ''
print ('Congratulations, you have completed the ' + str(level) + ' level, with a score of ' +
       str(score) + ' out of ' + str(guesses) + ' guesses')
```

For an online course, I am trying to make a fill in the blank quiz that's supposed to ask the user to pick a difficulty, and each difficulty consists of 5 questions. When the user guesses correctly, the answer must be displayed with the correct answer, and otherwise the user is prompted to answer again. This program is either not performing the way I want it to or has bugs

Comment: Since you haven't said *how* it is performing differently from how it is supposed to, or what these purported bugs are, I'm not sure how we are supposed to help you.

Comment: you cannot use `return` many times in the  function `check_answer` , at least how you did, you want to use print instead ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help. Changed code a bit.

```
print '''Welcome to General Quiz, a quiz where you are asked to select from three difficulty levels, with each level 
containing 5 fill in the blank questions'             
\nRules:
\n- These questions will be general knowledge based
\n- Your score, which will be shown in the end, will be based on how many correct 
answers you get compared to the number of guesses you take 
\n- It will not matter if you type anything lower or upper case print
\n- Some answers will require multiple words, so make sure you include spaces
\n- For numbered answers, sumbit answers in numbers, not words'''
level=None
while level not in ['easy', 'medium', 'hard']:
    level = raw_input ('Please select a difficulty (easy, medium, or hard): ').lower()
guesses, score = 0, 0
questions = ['The chemical symbol (O) means _____',
             '_____  is the best hockey player of all time',
             '_____ is the year Canada became an independant country',
             'The song "Sorry" was sung by _____',
             'Steve Jobs is one the founders of  _____ ',
             '_____ is Canadas very first capital',
             'The national team of _____ won the 2014 world cup',
             'In a computer, RAM stands for _____',
             'Your kidneys and your _____ are the organs that filter blood in your body',
             'In Breaking Bad, the wife of Walter is _____ White',
             'In NASAs apollo program, _____ of their missions successfully landed men on the moom',
             '_____ was the year the NFL was founded',
             'The first film to gross over one $1 billion is _____',
             '_____ is the business with the worlds largest revenue',
             'Lego was invented in the country of _____']
answers = ['oxygen', 'wayne gretzky', '1867', 'justin bieber', 'apple', 'kingston', 'germany', 'random access memory',
           'liver', 'skyler', '6', '1920', 'titanic', 'walmart', 'denmark']

dict = {'easy':0, 'medium':5, 'hard':10}
for i in xrange(dict[level], dict[level]+5):
    answer = raw_input(questions[i] + ': ').lower()
    while(answer != answers[i]):
        print('Incorrect, Try Again')
        guesses = guesses+1
        answer = raw_input(questions[i] + ': ').lower()
    print('Correct \n'+ questions[i].replace('_____',answer))
    score, guesses = score + 1, guesses+1

print ('Congratulations, you have completed the ' + str(level) + ' level, with a score of ' +
   str(score) + ' out of ' + str(guesses) + ' guesses')
```